Encrypted backup duplication without decrypting (rsync or other)
I have a LUKS filesystem in a sparse file, containing a lot of backed up files.
I would like to regularly copy this backup elsewhere (off-site), with read speed and bandwidth constraints (not transferring the whole file every time...). I would also like the file to remain sparse on the target, and make the update without knowing the encryption key (for simplicity but also security).
For initial copying I used the method from here which pipes the file as a tar archive through ssh. It's not nearly as fast as expected (it's taking around 7 days to copy a 14TB file that only weighs 6.2TB).
I wonder if using rsync (sparse mode) will actually tackle diffs in the file correctly and somewhat efficiently handle daily updates. I know I can also mount the two files and rsync from one to the other, but I'd rather have the files being identical and avoid unrequired mounting.
Would this work with rsync sparse ? What other solutions could be used ?
